# Understanding the .catch method in promises

Tags: javascript

I'm wanting to clarify how a promise is passed to `.catch` and what `.catch` does with it.

Using this as an example:

```js
    function fetchDog(){
        fetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/fail")
        .then(response => response.json()) 
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log('Fetch problem');
        });
      };
      
    fetchDog();
```

Looking at this statement from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then):

> If the Promise that then is called on adopts a state (fulfillment or
> rejection) for which then has no handler, a new Promise is created
> with no additional handlers, simply adopting the final state of the
> original Promise on which then was called.

I translate that to mean, in my example, the `.then`s return a new promise that is a copy of the promise that `.then` was called on.

By the time it reaches `.catch`, I know that `.catch` prints something to the console. The [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) also says it behaves the same as calling `Promise.prototype.then(undefined, onRejected)`.

Therefore, based on this excerpt from the `.then` spec:

> If a handler function: doesn't return anything, the promise returned
> by then gets resolved with an undefined value.

I expect `.catch` to return a new promise that 'gets resolved with' an undefined value. (What exactly does that mean, for a promise object to get 'resolved with' an undefined value)?

Is this true?

Comment: Catch is just what happens when the promise gets rejected

Comment: `.catch()` doesn't do anything if the promise was resolved, it only calls its callback if the promise was rejected.

Comment: That sentence you quoted is garbage. I've fixed it on MDN.

Answer (score 2):

`.then()` calls its callback when the promise is resolved. `.catch()` only calls its callback when the promise is rejected.

If `fetch()` is successful, it resolves its promise, so only the `.then()` callbacks are called.

If `fetch()` gets an error, it rejects its promise, and the `.catch()` callbacks will be called. Also, if `response.json()` gets an error (e.g. the response was not valid JSON), it will reject the promise, and `.catch()` will call its callback.