# I'm trying to go step-by-step to see how Promise.prototype.catch receives a Promise. Is my understanding right?

Tags: javascript

```
    function fetchDog(){
        fetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/fail")
        .then(response => response.json()) 
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log('Fetch problem');
        });
      };
      
    fetchDog();
```

Using the above example I would like to clarify *how* `.catch` here receives the rejected Promise. It's also a good exercise in reading MDN for me.

1 .

Looking at this statement from [MDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62961614/understanding-the-catch-method-in-promises):

> If the Promise that then is called on adopts a state (fulfillment or
> rejection) for which then has no handler, a new Promise is created
> with no additional handlers, simply adopting the final state of the
> original Promise on which then was called.

I translate that to mean, in my example, the `.then`s return a new promise that is a copy of the promise that `.then` was called on.

2 .

The `Promise.prototype.catch` [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) also says it behaves the same as calling `Promise.prototype.then(undefined, onRejected)`.

I interpret this to mean, in my example, that the first callback in `catch` is the `onRejected` parameter. Therefore, when `catch` receives a rejected promise, it executes `console.log('Fetch problem');`.

I also interpret this to mean that when `catch` invariably receives a fulfilled promise, it returns `undefined`? (I haven't thought of a way to test this in the console).

3 .

I also read in the `.then` spec:

> If a handler function: doesn't return anything, the promise returned
> by then gets resolved with an undefined value.

Therefore, in my code snippet, I interpret this to mean `catch` returns a promise whose value is `undefined`.

Based on this understanding, so long as the `fetch` line returned a fulfilled promise, this fulfilled promise would find its way to `catch` and `catch`'s callback wouldn't execute. `catch` would return `undefined`. (I can't think of a way to test this). I suspect my understanding is wrong.

Comment: We're did you get `fetchDog` from?, As there is a big mistake, is not returning the promise.

Comment: @Keith I purposefully set it up to fail if that's what you mean. My question is about understanding, sequentially, how `.catch` receives a promise, what it does with it and what `.catch` returns

Comment: The resolved value of the promise returned by `.catch` is not necessarily `undefined`. it is the return value of the callback passed to `.catch` that means you can return something arbitrary to be the resolved value of the promise returned by `.catch`

Comment: if the promise is not rejected and thus the `.catch` callback is not executed, `.catch` will pass through the resolved value of the promise. try this in chrome inspector: `Promise.resolve(1).catch(() => {})` and it will show the return value as `Promise {<resolved>: 1}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When `catch` invariably receives a fulfilled promise, it returns `undefined`?

No. Calling `.catch()` will always return a promise. It does that before even knowing whether the promise that it was called on is fulfilled, rejected or still pending.

> I interpret this to mean `catch` returns a promise whose value is `undefined`.

Yes. You can test this easily with

```js
function handleError(p1) {
    const p2 = p1.catch(err => {
        console.log('handling problem', err);
    });
    p2.then(res => {
        console.log('final promise fulfilled with', res);
    });
}
// handleError(Promise.resolve('success'));
handleError(Promise.reject('error'));
```